# Can a perl tk widget -command access itself?

Tags: perl, perltk

I have a perl TK widget which has a `-command` callback:

```
my $widget = $mw->Spinbox( -from => -1000, -to => 1000, -increment => 1, -width => 4, -textvariable => $textvariable, -command => sub { ... });
```

I would like to call a method on the widget inside the command sub.

How can I get a reference to the widget itself inside the callback in a generic way (not by accessing $widget by its name but something generic)?

I have looked into the `@_` arguments  that get passed into the sub, but they only contain the value of the widget, and the action (e.g. "up"). I was hoping to be able to access the widget via $self or "this" like in javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to pass arguments to callbacks:

1. Use a closure.
2. Pass an anonymous array containing the callback and the arguments.

In both the cases, you need to declare the variable containing the widget *before* you assign the object to it, otherwise it wouldn't be available.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Tk qw{ MainLoop };

my $mw = 'MainWindow'->new();

my $button1;
$button1 = $mw->Button(-text    => 'Start',
                       -command => sub { $button1->configure(-text => 'Done') }
                      ) ->pack;

my $button2;
$button2 = $mw->Button(-text    => 'Start',
                       -command => [
                           sub {
                               my ($button) = @_;
                               $$button->configure(-text => 'Done');
                           }, \$button2
                       ]
                      ) ->pack;

MainLoop();
```